# Converting Celsius degrees to Fahrenheit degrees using switch in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I'm a beginner c# programmer trying to program a simple app that shows a menu to the user. When option  1  is selected by the user at run-time, the program lists values from 0  to 100  Celsius degrees converted to Fahrenheit degrees. When option 2 is chosen,  the program calculates and displays a  list of values between 0  and 212  degrees in Fahrenheit converted to Celsius degrees. Use a constant for the values  100  and  212  in the related method.

The problem is that I'm only getting the option entered not a converted result. This is what I have done so far:
{

```
class TemperatureConverter
{
    private const int columns = 1;
    /// <summary>
    ///
    ///
    /// 
    /// </summary>

    public TemperatureConverter()
    {
        Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()

    {

        while (true)

        {
            int choice = ShowMenu();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 0:
                    return;
                case 1:

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    while (true)
                    {

                        Console.Write("Enter Celsius:");

                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double celsius))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ShowTableCelsiusToFahrenheit(celsius));
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            break;
                        }
                        
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter Fahrenheit:");
                        if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double fahrenheit))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ShowTableFahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit));
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You must enter 1 to convert to Celsius or 2 to convert to Fahrenheit or 0 to exit!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private double CelsiusToFarenheit(double celsius) => celsius * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0;
    private double FahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) => (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
    private string ShowTableCelsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius) => $"{celsius}°C is {CelsiusToFarenheit(celsius)}°F";
    private string ShowTableFahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) => $"{fahrenheit}°F is {FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit)}°C";

    public int ShowMenu()
    {
        int width = 28;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MAIN MENU");
            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(width, '-'));
            Console.WriteLine("Celsius to Fahrenheit".PadRight(width - 3) + ": 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Fahrenheit to Celsius".PadRight(width - 3) + ": 2 ");
            Console.WriteLine("Exit the program".PadRight(width - 3) + ": 0 ");
            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(width, '-'));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Your choice: ");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(line, out int choice))
            {
                return choice;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: How do you propose it should break out of the loop `while (choice != 0) ShowMenu();` you have written no logic for that here. Are you missing braces on the loop code? I note you could combine the `ShowTable...` functions into one as they do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I've done some refactoring for you so that you can see how this kind of code can be written. I've tried to logically extract the parts so there is a clear responsibility and flow for each part of the program.

I've also removed the automatic running of the code from the constructor. It's a bad idea to run code in the constructor other than code to set the initial conditions of the class.

Here's the refactored code:

```
void Main()
{
    var tc = new TemperatureConverter();
    tc.Start();
}

class TemperatureConverter
{
    public void Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int choice = ShowMenu();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 0:
                    return;
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter Celsius:");
                        if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double celsius))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(GetCelsiusToFahrenheitLine(celsius));
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter Fahrenheit:");
                        if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double fahrenheit))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(GetFahrenheitToCelsiusLine(fahrenheit));
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;              
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You must enter 1 to convert to Celsius or 2 to convert to Fahrenheit or 0 to exit!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private double CelsiusToFarenheit(double celsius) => celsius * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0;
    private double FahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) => (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
    private string GetCelsiusToFahrenheitLine(double celsius) => $"{celsius}°C is {CelsiusToFarenheit(celsius)}°F";
    private string GetFahrenheitToCelsiusLine(double fahrenheit) => $"{fahrenheit}°F is {FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit)}°F";

    public int ShowMenu()
    {
        int width = 28;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MAIN MENU");
            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(width, '-'));
            Console.WriteLine("Celsius to Fahrenheit".PadRight(width - 3) + ": 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Fahrenheit to Celsius".PadRight(width - 3) + ": 2 ");
            Console.WriteLine("Exit the program".PadRight(width - 3) + ": 0 ");
            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(width, '-'));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Your choice: ");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(line, out int choice))
            {
                return choice;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this doesn't do what has been asked of you in the text in your question. I'll leave that to you. One hint on that - there is no need to read in any temperature as input from the user.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried to write a for loop from 0-100  in intervals as follows:

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 4) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }: 
However, still wasn't able to figure out how to pass the (i) and convert it with the GetCelsiusToFahrenheitLine() method to display the converted result from 0-100.

Comment: @SadeerThaer - `GetCelsiusToFahrenheitLine((double)i)`.